# OS X initiate reboot from app without knowing user admin password

Tags: macos, mac, reboot

Is there a command to initiate a reboot (restart) from my app without knowing admin password of the user? For now I was using `sudo reboot`, but this requires admin password.

I need something similar as installers or updates do then.

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Comment: what about `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'restart' -e 'end tell'`

Answer (score 0):

Should not be possible. If it was, anybody could shut down your machine at random. Remember that OSX is basically a *multiuser* system (Unix at the core).

Comment: so only Apple can do it with it's installers?

Comment: @PrimozRose, They don't. Installers require root privileges. They probably get them by calling into a SUID binary that does the installing.